# Going through a window -- causes to forget?

Tags: segulah, architecture-design, memory

Someone told me today that they heard that going through a window to get from one place to another (from one room to another or from outside to inside or vice versa) is one of the things that causes a person to lose their memory. Is there any source for this?

Comment: It is not in masheches Horiyos,I would assume it is a European superstition.

Comment: @sam There are other sugyos that discuss memory besides Horayos 13b. That’s just the main one.